# "Send" button with AJAX loading page would not work

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-like, send

I have a typycal problem with "Send"/"Like" button.
My page contains dynamically updating content using the ajax requests.
So, after updating, my "Send buttons" did not work.
code of button:

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="${server}/book.html?currBookId=${book.id_book}"
                             style="margin-top: 5px;"></div>
```

standard code of inculding all.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
js = d.createElement(s);
js.id = id;
var lang = "${lang}";
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'#xfbml=1&appId=${fb_id}";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I tried to find answer here and found solution:
[stackoverflow solution post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4219729/how-to-add-a-facebook-like-button-to-an-ajax-driven-page)

I should add this:

```
 try{
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        } catch(ex) {}
```

After the AJAX call.
BUT!!
It is not working! Button is drawing now at Chrome browser, but in console I've got a lot of errors such:

```
 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://localhost:8080/catalog.html
 from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/send.php?api_key=API-
 KEY&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion
 %3D9%23cb%3Df847c7b0c%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ff8c34834
 c%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26relation%3Dparent.parent&colorscheme=light&
 extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2FMySite.com
 %2Fbook.html%3FcurrBookId%3D2668&locale=ru_RU&sdk=joey. 
 Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

And button do not work. In FF the button do not visible(this means that solution are not working in FF)

Have you any ideas how I can fix this problem?

Comment: I use FB.ui from facebook javascript SDK instead the standart "send" button. But I still intrested in solution of problem described upper.

Answer (score 1):

I got some problem too with asynchronous use of Like button.

I use a different code for including all.js and using FB.init (which is done by `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'#xfbml=1&appId=${fb_id}"`).

Here is what I use :

```
/* Ajax stuff in order to generate like button in xfbml or html5 */

if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
    /* If FB.init has already been called, just parse like button */
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('<YOUR-ID>'));
    /* You can also use FB.XFBML.parse() in order to parse the whole DOM, but I advise to integrate the Like / Send button into a div and parse it after */
}else{                       
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({ appId: <YOUR-APP-ID>, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
            /* FB stuff here, e.g. FB.event.suscribe */
    };      
    // Just load the script, no FB.init
    (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}                                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
}
```

It works perfect for me.

Concerning the error (Unsafe Javascript ...), it should appears with Chrome, not FireFox. It's Chrome-specific and is triggered because you're integrating an iFrame from another domain (FaceBook). AFAIK, there is no way to fix this error. Hope this helped.